# How to exclude some fields on TreeSet.contains but sort on all fields

Tags: java

Have some problem with TreeSet or I just realize that it doesn't work as I expected.
I need to exclude some fields when I check if the value already exists, but on sort it should use all the fields.
It looks like TreeSet.contains() use compare or compareTo (comparator, comparable) and not equals().

Here is some example:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class sorter {

    static class A {
        String name;
        int counter;

        public A(String a, int counter) {
            this.name = a;
            this.counter = counter;
        }
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
            return result;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj) return true;
            if (obj == null) return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
            A other = (A)obj;
            if (name == null) {
                if (other.name != null) return false;
            } else if (!name.equals(other.name)) return false;
            return true;
        }
    }

    public static class MyComparator implements Comparator<A> {
        @Override
        public int compare(A a, A b) {
            int c = b.counter - a.counter;
            if (c == 0) {
                return a.name.compareTo(b.name);
            };
            return c;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeSet<A> set = new TreeSet<>(new MyComparator());
        set.add(new A("a", 1));

        if (set.contains(new A("a", 2))) {
            System.out.println("'a' already exists, do count + count");
        }
    }
```

Feels like I breaking some law here, and should re-design it in some way?
Is it possible to achieve what I try to do with a TreeSet or should I go for a simple list?
In someway I have unique items and a list doesn't feel perfect either.

Any ideas?

Comment: See the note here about "consistent with equals" and why it's discouraged to do what you're thinking of.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comment: No, you can't really do what you're trying to do.  What would that even mean?

Answer (score 1):

You could change,

```
public int compare(A a, A b) {
    int c = b.counter - a.counter;
    if (c == 0) {
        return a.name.compareTo(b.name);
    };
    return c;
}
```

to be

```
public int compare(A a, A b) {
    if (Objects.equals(a, b))
       return 0;
    int c = b.counter - a.counter;
    if (c == 0) {
        return a.name.compareTo(b.name);
    };
    return c;
}
```

This way, if they are "equal" in your sense of equal, the TreeSet will exclude them. Otherwise you sort as you wish. As a note, the Objects.equals() will do the null checking for you.

Comment: I'm afraid that will have an impact on the uniqueness as well...
    set.add(new A("a", 1));
    set.add(new A("a", 2));
    set.add(new A("b", 1));
    set.add(new A("b", 2));

Output: (b, 2), (a, 1), (b, 1)

Answer (score 0):

It is using comparator to find equality.

Hash based collection only used equals and hashcode for equality.

But collection like tree using comparator for equality.

If two objects are equal then compare method should return true and vice versa.

```
set.contains(new A("a", 2)) its false because compare method wont return true`set.contains(new A("a", 1))` will return true because that method will return true.
```